# PHP Multiform Validation and Redirection

Tags: php, validation, post

I have `buy.php` with a **form** where you enter *items, quantity, shipping data, etc.*

When you click the **Submit button**, it posts back to `buy.php` `($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])` and does some data validation.

If there are fields missing or errors, they are highlighted. If everything is correct, I save the `$_POST` data in `$_SESSION` variables, then do a `header('Location: check.php')`, where I display the data so the buyer can check the info one last time before actually buying.

Now, if I'm in `check.php` and hit the Back button to `buy.php` so I can change stuff, the browser asks if I want to resend the POST data. I'm trying to avoid that.

**Anyone have any good advice or good practices for PHP Multiform validation?**

**Also, if I had n pages for the user to fill, `buy.php, buy2.php, ... buyn.php` before check.php would the same ideas still hold?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do a redirect to buy.php after saving to the session object, which then does a server redirect to check.php, it would mean when the user clicks back, they're going back to the GET request not the POST request

Answer (score 1):

Yes - I agree with above. I ALWAYS do a `redir` away from the last post, so clicking back bounces them back without that error OR re-submissions. it also avoids complications. u can always tag the `redir` link page with a `?m` or `&m` (i.e.: `page.php?m`) and have this at top of page: (use `elseif` there after)

```
if (isset($_GET['m'])) {
  echo 'order placed.';
}
else {
  //...
}
```

You can have it all on one page too. Just name the submit buttons `submit1`, `submit2`, like: (bear in mind if you use an image for submits, it becomes `$_POST['submit1_x']` :)

```
if (isset($_POST[submit1]) {
  //validate + save session data from form1
  //display form 2
} else if(isset($_POST[submit2])) {
  //validate + save session data from form2
  //display form 3
} else {
  //display first form
  //<input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Continue">
}
```